# Creating Managed Lists Like Versions and Components

Tags: jira

In JIRA, you can create custom fields which is good, but I feel that their field types are relatively weak.

For example, you can choose the 'Label' which you can add custom labels.  That is good, but I need to be able to choose from a list that already exists and do not want users to be able to create new ones freely.

So that leaves us with the option of using a Single Selection List or a Multi-Selection List.  The problem with this is the limited way of using it... drop-down.  I wish you could populate an item similar to the way you can add a predefined 'Version' or 'Component'.  The drop-down feels primitive.

So my question is: Are there a way of changing the selection interface of a list so that it mimics the way you would set a 'Target Version' for example (simply type it in freely and you can remove an item by clicking on the 'X' button).

Or if not, is there a way to create completely separate groups so that they can behave exactly like the 'Version' and the respective 'Version Picker' field.

I want my 'Customer' field to look and behave exactly like my 'Version' fields... not drop-down like.

Answer (score 0):

Versions and Components fields use autocomplete renderer, but

> For custom fields of type Multi Select, only the Select List Renderer is available. Furthermore, when modifying a field configuration, you will not be able to configure a Multi Select custom field's renderer.

see this link https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/16669/looking-for-a-custom-field-similar-to-the-component-field